# Swift Ambiguous Subscript Error On Array of Characters Not Consistent

Tags: arrays, swift

My code follows.  I've added line numbers for easier reference.

What I don't get is that line 32 fails with an error of "ambiguous subscript with base type '[Character]' and index type 'CountableClosedRange'", but lines 12, 16, and 20 work just fine.

```
 1 import Foundation
 2 
 3 struct PhoneNumber: CustomStringConvertible {
 4     var parsed: [ Character ]
 5     let badNum: [ Character ] = Array( "0000000000" )
 6     
 7     var number: String {
 8         return String( parsed )
 9     }
10    
11     var areaCode: String {
12         return String( parsed[ 0...2 ] ) // fine
13     }
14    
15     var exchange: String {
16         return String( parsed[ 3...5 ] ) // fine
17     }
18    
19     var subscriber: String {
20         return String( parsed[ 6...9 ] ) // fine
21     }
22    
23     var description: String {
24         return "(\( areaCode )) \( exchange )-\( subscriber )"
25     }
26    
27     init( _ startingNumber: String ) {
28         parsed = Array( startingNumber.components( separatedBy:
29             CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted ).joined() )
30         
31         if parsed.count == 11 && parsed[ 0 ] == "1" {
32             // parsed = parsed[ 1...9 ] // This Fails with error: ambiguous subscript with base type '[Character]' and index type 'CountableClosedRange<Int>'
33             
34             parsed.remove( at: 0 )   // This Works fine
35         } else if parsed.count != 10 {
36             parsed = badNum
37         }
38     }
39 }
40 
41 print( PhoneNumber( "+1.703.283.7360" ) )
```

Comment: `parsed[ 1...9 ]` is an `ArraySlice`, not an `Array`.

Comment: Besides the solution to your issue `parsed = Array(parsed[1...9])` Better so subclass UITextField and customize the user input as he types it.

Comment: Hamish, thanks.  I would not have guessed the error was a type mismatch given the error message.

Comment: Leo, thanks.  This is actually an Exercism.io problem, so my interface has to match the provided test suite.  However, I agree the interface is sub optimal, as is the case with most of the toy problems provided there.